# Visual Studio Designer / Button's location changes for unknown reason

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

Edit : Apparently, it seems that it is due to Panel having a BorderStyle set to FixedSingle. Set to none, the problem is "moving" button is solved, but I have no idea about what is going on. [end edit]

I have a  WinForm with a  Panel docked at the of the bottom on it which contains 3 buttons. They have a flat appearance and anchor is set to Top, Right and Bottom.

For some reason, when I show this Form, buttons are not visible because and the reason is that their location (.X only) changes. As a matter of fact, if I reset the location of these buttons and simply close the designer and open it again, I won't see them either because their location have been incremented by +500.

Any idea ? It's probably something really simple...

Comment: Are you buttons children of the panel, and not the form directly?

Comment: They are added to the Panel.

Comment: Is the form localized?

Comment: The form is not localize. And I try to re-create it, same thing keeps happening, while I'm using this king of "layout" on some other forms and have no problems... I checked the designer's generated code and I can't see anything different..

Comment: Do you find any solution? I have the same problem.